# Circular Linked List of Size K

Tags: java, list, linked-list, circular-list

I have a question on creating a single `Circular Linked List` without an add method. Just an inner class of Node, and then a constructor outside with a `toString` method. 
I am having a hard time `returning` the `List`, I continually return nothing. and I am lost to as why because I cannot implement an add method. I have to create a circular Linked List within my constructor, so that gives me a little insight on it. But how would I assign the values to my `Nodes` of `head` and `tail`

```
class Number{ 

class Node
{
        public int num=0;           // node's position in line
        public Node next=null;  // Reference to next node
        /**
        * Node constructor, initializes number
        */

        public Node(int number)
        {
               //
            num = number;
            next = null;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "" + num;
        }

}

private int number;
private Node head = null;   // Linked list of prisoners
private Node tail = null;   // Tracks end of list as it is constructed

/**
 * constructs a circular linked list of
 * @param n Nodes, current is the first Node and tail is the last Node (next of tail is current)
 */

public Number(int n)
{
    //
    number = n;
    LinkedList numb1 = new LinkedList();
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        numb1.add(i) //head I will have 1, 2, 3... n
    }
    head = null; //how would I make this reference head?
    tail = null; //how would I make this reference tail?
 }

/*
 * prints all Numbers starting from head until tail
 */
@Override
 public String toString()
 {
//
     String strVal = "";
     for (Node current = head; current != null; current = head.next) {
         strVal = strVal + current.num;
     }
     return strVal;
 }
```

I think the reason for this is in the for `loop`. 
By have the `current != null`, it keeps going because current can never be null as it references endlessly because it is a circular Linked List. However, it would at least return something instead of nothing.

Say I call
`Number newNum = new Number(6);` 
`System.out.println(newNum);`
I should out put
`1 2 3 4 5 6`

Comment: Wait, do you have a nested class named `Node$Node`?

Comment: No I do not. Would this be in my constructor?

Comment: This is selected copied-and-pasted bits of your code, apparently interspersed at random. We need the whole actual code to help.

Comment: This is actually all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. first you need to fix Number constructor.
   You should assign head to first node and tail to last node

> ```
>  public Number(int n) {
>         number = n;
>         head = new Node(0);
>         Node prev = head;
>         for (int i = 1; i <=number; i++) {
>             Node node = new Node(i);
>             prev.next=node; // head I will have 1, 2, 3... n
>             prev=node;
>         }
>         tail=prev;
>     }
> ```

2 . And in toString method you were always referring head.next which was causing infiinte loop as you never hit null (current != null will never become true in your code)

> ```
>  public String toString() {
>         String strVal = "";
>         for (Node current = head; current != null; current = current.next) {
>             strVal = strVal +" "+ current.num;
>         }
>         return strVal;
>     }
> ```

edit: One thing I would like to add is, your implemetation is of plain linked list and not circular linked list.. To make it circular, you should point tail to head,`tail=head`

Comment: So at the end of my constructor, I would decalre tail.next = head?

Comment: yes. you will also need to change some of your traversing logic in toString method.

Comment: When I did this, I got a NullPointerException, so this would mean that I'm using Null incorrectly when I do `tail.next = head` I understand the logic of have tails.next = head because now the last `node` is connected to the first `node` create the "circle" but why am I get this Exception?

Comment: Update: I got rid of the Exception, now I just have to fix my toString logic

Answer (score 1):

Go with this data structure

```
class CList {

 int size;
 CNode head;

class CNode {
 int data;
 CNode next; 

}

}
```

In the constructor for CList initialise `head` to `null` and `size` to 0.